# asp.net (VB) mono encrypt of web.config connectionStrings section not working right

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption, mono

I have posted this question on Stack Exchange, but Xamarin support point to Stack Overflow, so I will cross posted here.  I will also try the Xamarin forum directly.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269017/mod-mono-on-sles-12-1-fails-to-encrypt-asp-net-web-config

Comment: did you find an answer for that yet? If so, please post it ;)

Comment: @nozzleman : Sorry, no solution yet for encrypting the web.config via mono / ASP.Net.  I will definitely post one if I find it. 

I did try the OpenSuse Factory repo for installing mono on SLES 12.1 instead of using the Xamarin repo.  Same results.  I had other issue with the CheckboxList not keeping state, but I did fix that issue.

Comment: well, we got it working for encrypting, unfortunately, decrypting still fails :(

Comment: @nozzleman That's 1/2 good.  I am not sure what I have missing or configured wrong.  I have the odd result of having the file mostly disappear on encrypting. 

One point worth mentioning is that the encryption must be performed on the same box as the decryption.  So somehow you need to perform a one-time encryption on the target system (in production).  Decryption should be done automatically when accessing the value.  
Care to share your encrypting code method?

Comment: Yeah, i know. We got it working both ways on Windows already but somehow, decrypting on Mono fails, we suppose its a bug. Ill tell my colleague to share the result next week ;)

Comment: @nozzleman 
Did you ever get the mono asp.net web.config encryption working?

Comment: unfortunately not